# Restrict other administrator to delete or edit SUPER ADMIN (First Admin)

Tags: wordpress

I am running a WordPress website and I need to have multiple admins in my website but want all the admins to be restricted to edit/delete me (superadmin).

Please let me know how to dot it without using any plugin.

Thanks Sanny

Answer (score 0):

You can do that via functions.php,

```
// Remove a capability from a specific user.
$user_id = // The ID of the user to remove the capability from.
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->remove_cap( 'delete_users' );
```

Just assign userIDs and remove their capability to delete users.

Comment: Issue - (a) I want to restricts multiple admins and this must be an automated loop rather than giving ID (b) this way admins won't be able to delete any users, I want just not to allow to delete superadmin ( ID = 1)..

Comment: Ok here is the same question may be helps you : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104808/prevent-admin-user-to-edit-see-super-admin-from-users-list

Answer (score 0):

Adminimize plugin is correct in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I use **[Hide Super Admin Users](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hide-super-admin-users/)** plugin to remove the Super Admin from view of everyone but other Super Admin's